# Add error handling for interface

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have method which returns a interface and then I am trying to call some method from this interface.
So, I need to add error handling in to returned interface to track if user calls not exiting methods.

```
 let someInterface = await Controller.getApi('StatusData');
 let response   = await someInterface.getMyInfo(); // this method dosen't exists, so I need to add proper error handling in to returned 'someInterface'.
```

Comment: use try and catch

Comment: I need to add it in to returned interface, because I have lot of calls of this interface and it will be hard to cover all of them

Comment: I agree with @FadiAboMsalam, try catch is a beautiful tool.

Comment: Also besides of `try catch`, you can listen to [window.onerror](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror)

Comment: `I need to add it in to returned interface, ` then show the interfaces code....

Answer (score 0):

using [try catch](https://blog.grossman.io/how-to-write-async-await-without-try-catch-blocks-in-javascript/), should resolve your issue

```
try {
       let response = await someInterface.getMyInfo(); 
       if(!response) console.log("no response found")
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e); // catch error
    }
```

Comment: I need to add it in to returned interface, because I have lot of calls of this interface and it will be hard to cover all of them

Comment: Look at the link i've added to my answer, it should explain in detail how to catch error, i do think try, catch is your answere, maybe you should chain promises then use a catch or so..